# same struct for sending and receiving json data in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I want to use the same model struct for sending parameters and receiving JSON response from an API.

I want to send email and password and receive JSON response message.

But when I declare a property referencing another model in my user model, I am forced to provide a value.

My API does not return the parameters email and password, it simply returns an array if login is unsuccessful and returns the user info on successful login.

this is the json response on error :

```
Optional({
    errors =     {
        msg = "USER_DOES_NOT_EXIST";
    };
```

this is my model I used to post:

```
struct LoginUser: Codable {
    let email: String?
    let password: String?
}
```

this is the response on successful login:

```
Optional({
    token = 267e6a9d5a128fb1f44e670fcd89793af50fa9a831e6ae7dc2f0592b508bd224a71290fbdf1619cf52ed0f2c034b26383b915343f3822a52e1386c042484744b71811f80d3cb663fc76a6cc74d4866737421e3b9d62e35b415c0f7c385e5c70d472a5facf7f0101165d321c35eb20ae5f8bb32f06120e66a42de47c79a7587a2aa7f81f35c3821b9418e0c9142a7ec2b67b9755d3e17753dd8f1cdf3f71c0816627e2be26485f9b50ee1ad96a867856f0de736963c5ff59e9e37e92d5f3386f7;
    user =     {
        "_id" = 5e52c0c5cf65d33726a98590;
        email = "test7@gmail.com";
        "first_name" = gagz;
        "last_name" = bhullar;
        verified = 0;
    };
})
```

I want to modify my loginUser model such that it can both receive and send data.

is it possible?
if not, why?

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: if you aren't sending and receiving all of the same properties on send and receive, then they shouldn't be the same model. Otherwise your email and password would likely need to be optional to parse the response, but they should not be optional for making the request. So this is not a good way to do it

Comment: What is your request body? Where are your sending parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an API which returns two different models on success and failure I highly recommend to use an enum with associated values. The benefit is you get rid of the tons of optionals (and `if let` expressions) and you can use a descriptive `switch` for the success and failure cases.

```
enum Response : Decodable {

    case success(UserResponse)
    case failure(ErrorResponse)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        do {
            let userData = try container.decode(UserResponse.self)
            self = .success(userData)
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            let errorData = try container.decode(ErrorResponse.self)
            self = .failure(errorData)
        }
    }
}
```

And these are the corresponding structs

```
struct ErrorResponse: Decodable {
    let errors: [String:String]
}

struct UserResponse: Decodable {
    let token : String
    let user: User
}

struct User: Decodable {
    
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case id  = "_id"
        case email
        case firstName  = "first_name"
        case lastName  = "last_name"
        case verified
    }
    
    let id, email, firstName, lastName : String
    let verified : Int // maybe Bool
    
}
```

To send only two key-value pairs an extra struct and `Codable` is overkill. Create a temporary `[String:String]` dictionary and encode it with `JSONSerialization` or create the JSON `Data` directly for example

```
func jsonSendData(email: String, password: String) -> Data {
    let jsonString =
    """
    {"email":"\(email)","password":"\(password)"}
    """
    return Data(jsonString.utf8)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it is recommended to create separate model for handling the *failure* and *success* cases, still if you want to create a single model, you can do it like so,

```
struct LoginUser: Codable {
    let email, password, token, id, firstName, lastName: String?
    let verified: Int?
    let errorMessage: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case email, token, _id, firstName, lastName, verified, user
        case errors, msg
        case password
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        token = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .token)
        if container.contains(.user) {
            let user = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .user)
            id = try user.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: ._id)
            email = try user.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .email)
            firstName = try user.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
            lastName = try user.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .lastName)
            verified = try user.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .verified)
            errorMessage = nil
        } else if container.contains(.errors) {
            let errors = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .errors)
            errorMessage = try errors.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .msg)
            id = nil
            email = nil
            firstName = nil
            lastName = nil
            verified = nil
        } else {
            id = nil
            email = nil
            firstName = nil
            lastName = nil
            verified = nil
            errorMessage = nil
        }
        password = nil
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(email, forKey: .email)
        try container.encode(password, forKey: .password)
        //add the keys that you want to send in the request...
    }
}
```

Since, you haven't added the the *JSON* that you want to send in the request, I've assumed that you're only sending `email` and `password` in the request. You can add more in the above `encode(to:)` method.