# How to print error message while parsing in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, error-handling, codable

**this is json error structure:**

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "error": {
        "code": "-32700",
        "message": "Parse error",
        "meaning": "Could not decode token: Error while decoding to JSON: Syntax error"
    }
}
```

this is success response structure:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 371,..... so on data
```

here am unable to print error > message in my code

**code:** here able to print json response result or error dictionary in `case .success(_)` print statement but how to print only `error > meaning`

how to print error's `"Parse error"` in below code, please guide me

```
class GeneralResponse<T: Codable>: Codable {
    var result: T?
    let error: ErrorClass?
}

struct ErrorClass: Codable {
    let code, message, meaning: String?
}

struct RequestObject {
    var params: [String: AnyObject]? = nil
    var method: HTTPMethod
    var path: String
    var isTokenNeed: Bool = false
    var vc: UIViewController?
}

class NetworkManager {
    
    private let decoder: JSONDecoder
    static let sharedInstance = NetworkManager()
    
    public init(_ decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()) {
        self.decoder = decoder
    }
    
    public func serviceCall<T: Codable>(_ objectType: T.Type,
                                        with request: RequestObject,
                                        completion: @escaping  (T?, Error?) -> Void)  {
        
        
        let paramsDict  = ["jsonrpc" : "2.0", "params" : request.params ?? nil] as [String : Any?]
        
        
        AF.request(request.path, method: request.method, parameters: paramsDict as [String : AnyObject], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: "Accept": "application/json")
            .responseJSON { response in
                
                switch response.result {
                case .success(_):
                    do {
                        print("only json respopnse \(response)")
                        
                        let data = response.data
                        let responseData  = try self.decoder.decode(T.self, from: data ?? Data())
                        completion(responseData, nil)
                    } catch {
                        completion(nil, error)
                        print("in catch \(error)")
                    }
                case .failure(let AFError):
                    let error = AFError
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    print("failure error: \(error)")
                }
            }
    }
}
```

**o/p for error in above call with `print("only json respopnse \(response)")`**

```
only json respopnse success({
error =     {
    code = "-32700";
    meaning = "Token Signature could not be verified.";
    message = "Parse error";
};
jsonrpc = "2.0";
})
```

**EDIT 2:** here success response not coming in viewcontroller

```
struct PostModel: Codable {
    let jsonrpc: String?
    let result: PostResult?
}
struct PostResult: Codable {
    let users: [PostUser]?
}
struct PostUser: Codable {
    let id: Int?
}
```

and calling like this in vc

```
var k12Data: PostModel?

let paramet = ["location": "", "country": "", "gender": "", "keyword": ""] as [String : AnyObject]

let request = RequestObject(params: paramet, method: .post, path: "https://phpwebdevelopmentserv/", isTokenNeed: true, vc: self)
NetworkManager.sharedInstance.serviceCall(PostModel.self, with: request) { (response, error) in
print("viewcontroller data \(response)")
}
```

o/p

> viewcontroller data Optional(TestigAllInOne.PostModel(jsonrpc: nil, result: nil))

Comment: Please show how you are calling `serviceCall`?

Comment: What is `PostModel`?

Comment: @burnsi, I need to handle error in `NetworkManager` class not in viewcontroller

Comment: @burnsi, API json response model created using https://app.quicktype.io/

Comment: The best way is to decode the repsonse with `responseDecodable` directly into an enum with associated values, for example see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60372771/same-struct-for-sending-and-receiving-json-data-in-swift/60374710#60374710 , `responseJSON` is deprecated. And you can't be serious to send an UIViewController instance as parameter, parameters are always `[String:Any]` not `[String:AnyObject]`. And `(T?, Error?)` is outdated, there is `Result<T,Error>` to get rid of the optionals

Comment: I see who you are now, you asked this question before, and never responded to it, with your other fake account: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75027532/unable-to-get-json-response-for-post-api-with-alamofire-in-swift
See my `EDIT-1` to that question.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine, OMG, plzzz dont say fake account, there my question limit ENDs... and with this question here also my question limit ENDs... i am giving explanation to you bcz if i ask any question with another account you will say again this

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine, plz dont rude to anyone you have edited your question 2 days later that time i was logged out to that account... will respond you there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn´t show us your `Postmodel` so I am asuming it is of some type of `GeneralResponse<T>` class.

You should decode to your GeneralResponse class:

```
let responseData = try self.decoder.decode(GeneralResponse<T>.self, from: data)
```

now you can print your error if one exists:

```
print(responseData.error?.meaning ?? "no error")
```

and call your completion handler like this:

```
guard let result = responseData.result else{
    // unknown error has occured
    completion(nil, nil) // you probably need to create a custom error here
    return
}

completion(result, nil)
```

the main essence is to not pass `GeneralResponse` as argument to your function but the `result` type you are expecting. So if for example your `User` type looks like this:

```
struct User: Codable{
    var id: String
}
```

call it like this:

```
networkmanager.serviceCall([User].self, with: RequestObject(...)) { users, error in
    // users is of type `[User]` here.
}
```

Comment: i have added `PostModel` in my post... once go through it... in your answer able to print error and got response in `NetworkManager` but not getting response in viewcontroller

Comment: networkmanager.serviceCall([User].self, with: RequestObject(...)) { users, error in
    // users is of type `[User]` here.
}

Comment: this is not working.. where should change to get response

Comment: @Swift what is not working. You really need to more precise. According to your `PostModel` this should work. Please add the exact error message.

Comment: I have added my code in post `edit 2` section with output.. plz once gothrough

Comment: @Swift please read  my answer carefully and try to understand. I allready adressed this issue. You need to use `[PostUser].self` instead of `PostModel.self` as type while calling `serviceCall`.

Comment: yes, tried that one as well then got
`viewcontroller data nil
in catch The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.`

Comment: `NetworkManager.sharedInstance.serviceCall([PostUser].self, with: request) { (users, error) in`